# Can not run Sysinternals Process Explorer via Task scheduler (installed via winget on Win11)

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, process-explorer, sysinternals

I'm unable to setup the Process Explorer to run at startup via Task Scheduler. Regardless if I create the task via the Process Explorer menu 'Run at startup' or manually I am unable to make it work.

I've installed Systeinternals via winget:

```
> winget list sysinternals
Name               Id           Version     Source
----------------------------------------------------
Sysinternals Suite 9P7KNL5RWT25 2022.10.1.0 msstore
```

Running the task does nothing and there are no errors in the task history log. It is as if nothing happens. 'Run with highest privileges' also does nothing
What I find very odd about the installation is that `procexp.exe` is a 0kb file in the Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps folder. It has no icon but I can run it normally by double-clicking on it. However if I use Task Scheduler and I try to selected it (via Browser on Actions) I get the following error:

```
procexp.exe
The file cannot be accessed by the system.
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft is trying to abolish running interactive programs via the Task Scheduler. Why are you trying to do it this way, when you could just set it to run as a user Startup process? Or are you trying to do [boot time monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)?

Comment: Process Explorer has a menu option 'Run at Logon'. Setting this creates the Task scheduler task (which does not work). My attempt to create a similar task was just a way to try to figure out why the task is not running. The reason I want it running on logon is just because of system tray icons for CPU/HDD monitoring. Regarding your comment that this might be intentional: any source where this statement was made?

Comment: If you install Process Explorer from the System Internals (Microsoft) website, update your PATH variables, are you able to get the scheduled task to work?